# Typescript typings definition of a property

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a JavaScript object which stores a dictionary of words:

```
var Words = {}; 
Words.Account="Account";
Words.Account_Login="Account Login";
```

My Typescript definition looks like this:

```
declare class Words {
    Account: string;
    Account_Login: string;
}
```

To use it in my TypeScript I have to use "prototype". How can I not have to use prototype?

```
/// <reference path="../typings/words.d.ts" />
var abc = Words.prototype.Account_Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are accessing Account_Login through the Words class as if it is a static variable.

If you are creating a class `Words` then I would expect that you would be using it something like this:

```
var myWords = new Words();
var abc = myWords.Account_Login;
```

Maybe instead of a class definition you want to define an interface like the following:

```
declare interface IWords{
    Account: string;
    Account_Login: string;
}
```

Then taking your Words object make sure that you are using the interface that you defined

```
var myWords = Words as IWords;
var abc = myWords.Account_Login;
```

Answer (score 1):

@tj-rockefeller is correct, I also found if I also just made the Words static, I could use them as intended.

```
var Words = {}; 
  static  Words.Account="Account";
  static  Words.Account_Login="Account Login";
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?